# RxJava do multiple requests in serialized way

Tags: android, reactivex

i must do some retrofit calls from a list of ids (can be up to 50 easy)

my actual code:

```
idsList
.subscribeOn(scheduler.computation())
                .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
                .flatMapIterable { ids -> ids }
                .flatMap { id -> requestEmployeeData(id) }
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            success ->
                            println("success")
                        },
                        { error ->
                            error.printStackTrace()
                        }
)
```

the issue with this is that it spawn all the requests in the same time and i dont want this behaviour, i need it to do the first one, wait response, process, finish, do the next one till the end

is there any way to only go to the next item on idsList only when the previously `:Observable<Response<SyncEmployeeData>>` ends?

Comment: I believe `concat` should do that for you

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly any working example using some kind of requests ? thx

Comment: Have you tried using **flatMap** instead of ur first **flatMapIterable**? You can also try **cache()** and it will store all items indefinitely

Comment: @Ispam not yet, how to make flatMap emit only one id per time and wait for the previously flatMap to finish?

Comment: tested flatMap solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

What does requestEmployeeData return? 
It seems that it returns another Observable and with flatMap it gives many threads to you.